# ConstraintLayout how to pack keeping the same ratios of distance

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout that exceeds the view boundaries after applying all the margins I'm looking for. I read that applying a chain will make it keep the same ratios while packing all the elements inside the view boundaries.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Texto2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="dsadsadsadsadasd"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/texto1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="gggggg" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/tut_first_img"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Texto2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ggggggggggggggggggggg"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what's happening without margins after all margins applied it will exceed the view screen. How can I compact it while keeping the ratios? Also, how can I center all views in a vertical line?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Do you have any problem with my solution? I mean are you facing any issues or the coding is not how you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code as per your use case, pls. check:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00ff00">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Texto2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dsadsadsadsadasd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/img"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/texto1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="gggggg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Texto2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/botao"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Texto2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ggggggggggggggggggggg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/img" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope it helps you, looking forward if any further help is required from my end.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` You use much of these lines, why are they necessary ?

Comment: These are necessary because they connect the start of the view to the start of the parent layout and the end of the view to the end of the parent layout and then (horizontally) centre it by default. You can also control its value (the value for positioning the view horizontally) by using the horizontal_bias tag if you wish, the default value for it is 0.50 i.e. at 50% of the screen (in horizontal manner) by default. The same goes for top and bottom tags when they are connected with some view and in that case the vertical_bias tag is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Texto2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="dsadsadsadsadasd"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/texto1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="gggggg"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/botao"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Texto2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="ggggggggggggggggggggg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just copy paste it and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that the below mentioned code helps you in achieving your desired layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Texto2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dsadsadsadsadasd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/texto1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="gggggg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/Texto2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/texto1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/botao" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/botao"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ggggggggggggggggggggg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Screenshot (of the UI achieved by the above code):**

[image]

The chain symbol (right most symbol; below the first view in the layout) can be used to toggle and thus apply different chain styles (as per your need), if you aren't familiar with [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).